# Lost filter by default ag-grid column when I use the enterprise version of ag-grid ANGULAR 9

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In my file `package.json`  for my `angular` project :

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLvJD.png)

in my `main.ts` file I have :

```
image.png
```

but I have this error message which is showing when I bring up the console and when I try to use `ag-grid` default filters as shown in the message below

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tfPh.png)

there I have the filters which are displayed normally
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtXkO.png)

Comment: Please provide more and better details in your question. It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: in fact, the problem is very simple, is that I lose the default ag-grid filters when I import the enterprise version to my project. I do not understand why. I thank you for your feedback.